# Qt-Designer's spinbox does show or store data

Tags: qt-designer

I am new in Qt Designer. I created a user form to show and insert data to a shapefile. Everything works well, except the spinboxes. The fieldtype in the shapefile is integer with fieldlength 10. The shapefile already contains data. In the userform these data in the spinboxes are not shown, the spinbox shows "NULL". When I look in the attribute table data also are missing, even they have been there before. When I insert data the field length is not 10 as it was before, but only 2. The inserted data are not stored.

What's the problem?

Comment: You have to write some code to handle the spinboxes at the userform. The class is **QSpinBox**.